# Power BI Embedded, updating a dashboard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am referring to the problem of updating a dashboard that has been published to azure via power BI embedded ([Azure tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started/)).

When I publish to azure an updated version of a dashboard (using step 6 of the desktop solution provided on the link above), I am able to publish the updated pbix file to the same workspace and dataset name. When I retrieve the list of datasets for the workspace I can see both the old and new dashboard with the same name and different id. I have found this confusing as I would have expected using the same name would overwrite the old version of the pbix file.

What would be the recommended procedure to update a dashboard? Would it be to use a new name for the dataset each time? This doesn't seem ideal as it can have implications as well in the embedding web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience what I have done is to just delete the original and upload again with the same information.  I don't rely on the IDs generated from the power bi workspace, I keep track of everything in a table I control.  For example I have a table which holds the power bi meta data with an ID I give it.  If I ever need to upload a new version of the PBIX I would delete the one from the azure workspace and upload a new one using the same information and then get that new ID and store it with my local ID.

So in use I would look up the report based on my local ID in my application to get the information needed to pass to power bi api to then view the report.

Hope this helps.